# $GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types'][$myCType]['columnsOverrides']['imagecols']['config']['items'] not overriding default list

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-7.6.x

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types'][$myCType]['columnsOverrides']['imagecols']['config']['items'] = [[2,2],[3,3]];
```

But above not working it just replace fist two items with my list but other items are still visible how can i override items array for my custom ctype?

Comment: have you tried adding empty elements (`,,,` or `NULL` or `[]` or `[,]`) to your list, so the third, fourth, ... elements get overwritten with empty entries?

Comment: yes they are then either gives error or empty items

Answer (score 0):

It seems, \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ArrayUtility::mergeRecursiveWithOverrule(), which is used to handle the columnsOverrides, does allow unsetting a key (or array), but not replacing a substructure.
Maybe it's possible to find a combination of unsetting and afterwards merging with new values.

Comment: Hmm i have also tried to unset and then assign it but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use TCEFORM to solve your task.

```
TCEFORM.tt_content.imagecols.types.myCType.keepItems = 2,3
```